# Svelte Sapper onMount data only updates on login after a page reload?

Tags: rest, svelte, sapper, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am trying to fetch data on a component from an external api. I have the data request on a Sidebar component in an onMount block.

When a user logs in and routes to the page with the Sidebar the data displayed is from the last session. I need to refresh the page to see the current data.

How can I fix this process so the data fetched is always current to the logged in user?

**Nav.svelte**

Inside the Nav component I have the logout function where there is a logout button on the nav.

```js
async function logout() {
    await post(`auth/logout`);
    session.set({ token: null, user: null })
    goto("/");
  }
```

**Sidebar.svelte**

Inside the Sidebar component I have the request for data to the api.

```html
<script>
import { goto, stores } from "@sapper/app";
const { session } = stores();

let accountData = [];

onMount(async () => {
    if ($session.token) {
        const res = await api.get(`accounts`, $session.token, $session.user._id)
        accountData = res.data;
    } else {
        accountData = [];
    }
})
</script>

{#each accountData as item}
  <div>
    <h3>{item.accountName}</h3>
    <p>{item._id}</p>
  </div>
{/each}
```

Comment: Does the Sidebar.svelte Component ever get unmounted? If not, your best bet would be to use one of the update lifecycle hooks.

Comment: @Gh05d I have tired placing accountData in onDestroy. Nothing I try seems to work. Does a component get destroyed only if the components is not rendered. This sidebar component is always rendered as it's nested in the Nav which is inside the _layout.svelte file. Not sure what else I can try here to refresh the data.

Comment: You could look into the update lifecycle functions and maybe the tick function. Maybe pass a property that initiates a refetch?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to fetch that data whenever the session store is updated. The easiest way is probably to use `session.subscribe`:

```html
<script>
import { onMount } from "svelte";
import { goto, stores } from "@sapper/app";
const { session } = stores();

let accountData = [];

onMount(() => {
    const unsubscribe = session.subscribe(async ($session) => {
        if ($session.token) {
            const res = await api.get(`accounts`, $session.token, $session.user._id)
            accountData = res.data;
        } else {
            accountData = [];
        }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
});
</script>

{#each accountData as item}
  <div>
    <h3>{item.accountName}</h3>
    <p>{item._id}</p>
  </div>
{/each}
```